# Need suggestion with Git commit Erro

Tags: git, github

I am getting this error on git and not able to commit changes any more.
I have not worked on Git alot and not sure what I am supposed to do to get passed the error.

```
✖ EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Git\visualization…
↓ Skipped because of previous git error. [SKIPPED]
↓
  ✖ lint-staged failed due to a git error. [SKIPPED]
↓
  ✖ lint-staged failed due to a git error. [SKIPPED]

  ✖ lint-staged failed due to a git error.
  Any lost modifications can be restored from a git stash:

    > git stash list
    stash@{0}: automatic lint-staged backup
    > git stash apply --index stash@{0}

husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

When I do git status, it just gives me the name of the file that I need to commit

```
MINGW64 /c/git/visualization (405)
$ git status
On branch 405
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/405'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   map/components/Graph.tsx
```

I try to commit it
git commit -am"Added font-family barlow"

It tries to process and I end up getting the above error message.

----------------Update 1.. Content of pre-commit-----------
#!/bin/sh
# husky

```
# Created by Husky v4.2.5 (https://github.com/typicode/husky#readme)
#   At: 7/22/2020, 1:52:38 PM
#   From: undefined (https://github.com/typicode/husky#readme)

. "$(dirname "$0")/husky.sh"
```

Comment: I guess we need the content of husky.sh

Answer (score 1):

The repository you are working on has a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that is failing for some reason. A pre-commit hook is a script that git runs every time you make a commit.

You could probably bypass the hook by moving or deleting the `.git/hooks/pre-commit` file, but it would be best to look at what is inside that file and fix the underlying issue.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I am posting the content of the pre-commit file, check under update 2. Last it was changed was 7/22 and I have been committing code every day.

Comment: Looks like whatever is inside `husky.sh` is trying to run `open` on a file, which it doesn't have permission to do. Something about your file system permissions must have changed.

Comment: thanks for your help. I was able to solve it by closing all my git applications and cmd line.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it by closing all my git applications and cmd lines. Seems like I had git bash application and git bash cmd line both open and they caused an overlap. Closed all that and error went away.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to verify before commit, then:
git commit -m "new commit" --no-verify

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem once. I have tried to empty everything inside .git/hooks folder and it works. You can try this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to track a file that was modified and I didn't pay attention to it. once i runned `git add .` again and it worked

Answer (score 0):

next helped:

1. move .git folder out (into temp folder)
2. create empty .git folder
3. copy contents of .git folder back into newly created

...commit

Answer (score 0):

For me it helps:

1. run git bash in my project folder from windows explorer
2. execute "git stash"
3. execute "git drop"
4. execute "git clear"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.git` folder then using these commands:

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourgithubusername/xxxxx.git
git push -u origin main
```

After doing this, go to the source control and start to commit.